# ImportError: No module named date_capnp

Tags: nupic

While trying to understand nupic minecraft demo code. I am running nupic_client.py from pycharm IDE. Python version is 2.7.8 on Mac OS with nupic dowloaded as package version 0.2.8

On running nupic_client.py following error occurs *ImportError: No module named date_capnp*

Any help is appreciated.

***Stack Trace:***

```
File "/Users/msghotra/Sandbox/CodeHub/datascience/workspace/nupic_minecraft/nupic_client.py", line 5, in <module>
    from nupic.frameworks.opf.modelfactory import ModelFactory
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/frameworks/opf/modelfactory.py", line 32, in <module>
    from clamodel import CLAModel
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/frameworks/opf/clamodel.py", line 44, in <module>
    from nupic.encoders import MultiEncoder, DeltaEncoder
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/encoders/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from date import DateEncoder
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nupic/encoders/date.py", line 28, in <module>
    from nupic.encoders.date_capnp import DateEncoderProto
ImportError: No module named date_capnp
```

Comment: looks like there is an issue in backlog **#2166 opened 16 days ago by marcino239**

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean nupic==0.2.3, since 0.2.8 isn't out yet.  This should be fixed with https://github.com/numenta/nupic/pull/2231.  More details are available in the issue you referenced (the direct link is https://github.com/numenta/nupic/issues/2166). Hope this helps!

**EDIT** This should now be resolved in `nupic==0.2.6`